# sed regexp - extra unwanted line in matching output

Tags: regex, sed

I have this file

```
~/ % cat t
---
    abc
def DEF    
ghi GHI
---
123
456
```

and I would like to extract the content between the three dashes, so I try

```
sed -En '{N; /^---\s{5}\w+/,/^---/p}' t
```

I.e. 3 dashes followed by 5 whitespaces including the newline, followed by one or more word characters and ending with another set of three dashes. This gives me this output

```
~/ % sed -En '{N; /^---\s{5}\w+/,/^---/p}' t
--- 
    abc
def DEF
ghi GHI
---
123
```

I don't want the line with "123". Why am I getting that and how do I adjust my expression to get rid of it? [EDIT]: It is important that the four spaces of indentation after the first three dashes are matched in the expression.

Comment: Do you need to include the `---` lines in the output? Or is it not necessary?

Comment: I don't think it is strictly necessary, although somehow maybe retaining the last one could be nice, as I need some delimiter to split the strings in the file afterwards.

Comment: Neither of these commands work. They both also match the lines "123" and "456" after the last three dashes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -En '/^---/{:a;N;/^ {4}\S/M!D;/\n---/!ba;p}' file
```

Turn on extended regexp (`-E`) and off implicit printing (`-n`).

If a line begins `---` and the following line is indented by 4 spaces, gather up the following lines until another begins `---` and print them.

If the following line does not match the above criteria, delete the first and repeat.

All other lines will pass through unprinted.

N.B. The `M` flag on the second regexp for multiline matching , since the first line already begins `---` the next must be indented.

Answer (score 0):

No need to use the pattern space here - a range pattern will do fine.

```
$ sed -n '/^---/,/^---/p' t 
---
    abc
def DEF    
ghi GHI
---
```

Tested in GNU sed 4.7 and OSX sed.

Comment: I apologize for not being totally precise in describing my object. But the expression must also match the four spaces of indentation in the first line after the first three dashes. If these spaces are not present, then I don't want it to match.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can use

```sh
perl -0777 -ne '/^---\R(\s{4}\w.*?^---)/gsm && print "$1\n";' t
```

*Details*:

- `-0777` - slurps the file into a single variable
- `^---\R(\s{4}\w.*?^---)` - start of a line (`^`), `---`, a line break, then Group 1: four whitespaces, a word char, then zero or more chars as few as possible, and then `---` at the start of a line
- `gsm` - `g`lobal, all occurrences are returned, `s` means `.` matches any chars including line break chars, as `m` means `^` now matches start of any line, not just string start
- `&& print "$1\n"` - if there is a match, print Group 1 value + a line break.